# Hi, I can't figure out how to fix this cursor error, "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow."

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm fairly new with using android studio and I'm not sure I can even do what I'm trying to get running here. 
I'm trying to run a few listviews pulling from the same table, when the program is ran it'll crash at this part saying about the cursor. Any ideas?

The logcat

```
    --------- beginning of crash
04-23 19:18:55.749 3100-3100/com.example.j3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.j3, PID: 3100
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.j3/com.example.j3.GroupList2}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at com.example.j3.GroupList2.onViewData(GroupList2.java:61)
        at com.example.j3.GroupList2.onCreate(GroupList2.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Main code

```
package com.example.j3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroupList2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView, listView2, listView3, listView4;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button clear;
    ArrayList<String> listname, listLearningstyle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_list);

        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv2);
        listView3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv3);
        listView4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv4);



        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        onViewData();
        onViewData2();
        onViewData3();
        onViewData4();

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteAll();
                openStudents();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onViewData() {

         listname = new ArrayList<String>();
         listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select  NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='Visual' or LEARNINGSTYLE='VA' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 1st list view

    public void onViewData2() {


         listname = new ArrayList<String>();
         listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='Kinesthetic' or LEARNINGSTYLE='VK' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc  ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }

        listView2.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 2nd list view

    public void onViewData3() {

         listname = new ArrayList<String>();
         listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='Aural' or LEARNINGSTYLE='VA' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        listView3.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 3rd list view

    public void onViewData4() {

         listname = new ArrayList<String>();
         listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor   c = db.rawQuery("select NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='VAK' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        listView4.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });

    } //shows the 4th list view


    public void deleteAll() {
        db.delete("id", null, null); //delete all rows in a table
    }

    public void openStudents() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Students.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

the adapter list

```
package com.example.j3;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterList2 extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> n, p;
    GroupList2 l;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AdapterList2(GroupList2 data, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> learningstyle) {
        this.l = data;
        this.n = name;
        this.p = learningstyle;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(data);
    }

    @Override    public int getCount() {
        return n.size();
    }

    @Override public Object getItem(int i) {
        return n.get(i);
    }

    @Override    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,viewGroup,false);
        TextView tvname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvlearningstyle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvlearningstyle);
        tvname.setText(n.get(i));
        tvlearningstyle.setText(p.get(i));
        return view;
    }

}
```

the adapter xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.016"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvlearningstyle"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have been trying to solve this for a few days now, I would love some input.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your "Main Code", there are lines like this:

```
Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select  NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='Visual' 
or LEARNINGSTYLE='VA' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
```

which selects only 1 column: `NAME` from the table `id` (is this really a table name?).
Then there are lines like these:

```
listname.add(c.getString(1));
listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
```

The column indexes of the Cursor are `0` based, meaning that the 1st column's index is 0 and the 2nd column's index is 1, but you try to access `1` and `2`!
But, remember, the query fetched **only 1 column**. 
Change to this:

```
Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select NAME, LEARNINGSTYLE from id where LEARNINGSTYLE ='Visual' 
or LEARNINGSTYLE='VA' order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
```

This query fetches 2 columns: `NAME` and `LEARNINGSTYLE`.
And add the values to the lists like this:

```
..................................................
listname.add(c.getString(0));
listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(1));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Yeah that fixed that error, but now I've got a new one :(

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.j3.GroupList2.onViewData4(GroupList2.java:111)
        at com.example.j3.GroupList2.onCreate(GroupList2.java:41)

Comment: This post answers your question. For any other problem you must post another question with all the relevant code.